# Can someone explain how WebDriver casting to TakesScreenShot in Selenium working

Tags: java

This is a *JAVA* conceptual question, not related to Selenium.

For a sample code like :

```
// Taking a screenshot in Selenium
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
File srcFile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

When I observe, *WebDriver* and *TakesScreenshot* do not share a common super interface. In that case how can casting be valid and why not a *ClassCastException*?

***It would be really great if this can be explained with an example.***

Comment: `ChromeDriver` implements `TakesScreenshot`.

Comment: Does `ChromeDriver` implement `TakesScreenshot`? Where do you get the idea that there should be a shared super interface?

Comment: But ChromeDriver object is type casted to WebDriver and WebDriver does not implement TakesScreenshot. Can you explain more here?

Comment: @Kayaman, To your first question - ChromeDriver implements RemoteWebDriver which inturn implements TakesScreenShot. And to the second one I guess I had wrong understanding about casting. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Whether casting succeeds or not depends on the *concrete, execution-time type* of the object - not on the compile-time type of the expression. For example: `Object x = "text"; String y = (String) x; // Succeeds`. The concrete execution-time type of the object here is `ChromeDriver`, which implements `TakesScreenshot`, so the cast succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take Selenium out of the picture and use built-in types for simplicity. Your code is similar (in terms of casting) to this:

```java
Comparable<String> text = "hello";
int length = ((CharSequence) text).length();
```

This compiles and executes without an exception because:

- `"hello"` is a `String`
- `String` implements both `Comparable<String>` and `CharSequence`
- The cast to `CharSequence` is concerned by the *execution-time* type of the object that the value of `text` refers to, not the *compile-time* type `text`

At execution time, the value of `text` refers to a `String` object ("hello"). The fact that the compile-time type is `Comparable<String>` is irrelevant when it comes to the cast - so long as it's *possible*. (If you try to cast an expression with a compile-time type which can't *possibly* be valid, e.g. casting from `String` to `InputStream`, then you'll get a compile-time error. But when the compiler is happy that the cast could *potentially* succeed, the compile-time type of the variable is irrelevant when it comes to the execution-time handling of the cast.)

Answer (score 0):

Non Primitive typecasting is possible in following 2 cases.

1. There should be an Is A relationship between two objects
2. Two objects (class or interface) should have a common child

Since webdriver and takescreensht have the commom child (Remote webdriver) we can perform typecasting between webdriver and takescreenshot.